# Find Two Series Solutions:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, bessel-functions

> Find two series solutions of the form
>   $$
> x^{1/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_nx^n\\
> x^{-1/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }b_nx^n
> $$
>   of the Bessel equation of order $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$:

$$
x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-\alpha^2)y=0\\
u=x^{\frac{1}{2}}y\\
u''+\left(1+\frac{1/4-\alpha^2}{x^2}\right)u=0\\
u''+u=0\\
u=\cos x, u=\sin x\\
y=x^{-1/2}\cos x,y=x^{-1/2}\sin x\\
y=x^\alpha\left[1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^m}{(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+m)m!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m}\right]$$
$$y_2=x^{-\alpha}\left[1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^m}{(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+m)m!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m}\right]$$

> But where to from here?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html